# Changing in PHTML in Vendor Folder does not affect frontend

Tags: magento2, phtml, vendor

I changed the `subscribe.phtml` in

> vendor/magento/module-newsletter/view/frontend/templates/subscribe.phtml.

I just changed:

```
<span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Subscribe')) ?></span> 
to
<span>Test</span>
```

I cleared everything with :

```
sudo rm -rf pub/static
sudo rm -rf var/cache
sudo rm -rf var/composer_home
sudo rm -rf var/generation
sudo rm -rf var/page_cache
sudo rm -rf var/view_preprocessed
```

and then started `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`.

But nothing changed. Why ? Please help

Answer (score 0):

Please try this solution.

> 1) Magento way

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$escaper = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Escaper')->escapeHtml(__('Subscribe'));
```

> 2) Core Php way

```
 htmlspecialchars(__('Subscribe'), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `subscribe.phtml` is override by theme or other modules.
First, enable template hint and check from where `subscribe.phtml` Calling.

https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-enable-template-path-hints-magento-2.html
According to template hint modify the template file.

But you don't work directly at the vendor folder. Override via Theme or Module

You can follow https://www.classyllama.com/blog/template-override-m2 for **override the templates files location.**

Comment: Yes but theoretically it should work right ?

Comment: And i activated template hints. This is the Path:

vendor/magento/module-newsletter/view/frontend/templates/subscribe.phtml

So i edited the correct file. I have Redis and Varnish activated. Maybe this is the reason ?

Comment: Yes, you have to flush redis cache